# "American Billions" puzzle: Find a 10-digit number (no repeats), where the first $n$ digits give a number divisible by $n$, for all $n = 1,\ldots,9$

Tags: puzzle

I have no idea why the problem is apparently called this but here it is.

> Using only the digits $0$, $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $9$, find a ten-digit number such that the number up to the $n$-th digit is divisible by $n$, for all $n\in\{1,\ldots,9\}$.
>
> In other words, the first digit is divisible by $1$ (easy); the number made from just the first two digits is divisible by $2$ (again, easy - just make the second number even); and so on. *Since there are ten digits and only nine are needed to satisfy the divisibility rule, there should be one left over at the end.*

The closest I have gotten so far is the number $309258641$.
$$\begin{align}
3 &= 1 \times 3 \\
30 &= 2 \times 15 \\
309 &= 3 \times 103 \\
3092 &= 4 \times 773 \\
30925 &= 5 \times 6185 \\
309258 &= 6 \times 51543 \\
3092586 &= 7 \times 441798 \\
30925864 &= 8 \times 3865733 \\
309258641 &= \color{red}{\text{not divisible by $9$}} \\
309258647 &= \color{red}{\text{not divisible by $9$}}
\end{align}$$

However, this was obtained by trial and error (following some simple rules like the second digit must be even, and the first, second and third digits must add to a multiple of $3$, etc.).

My question is:

> Does anyone know of a systematic way of finding the answer, or showing that there isn't one?

Comment: it's called that because there are two systems that were once both in use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-52AI_ojyQ

Comment: "... divisible by $n$ for all $n \in \{0,\ldots,9\}$". Divisibility by zero is a tricky condition. :)  Do you mean "... divisible by $n$ for all $n \in \{1,\ldots,9\}$"?

Comment: If the last digit were $0$, then there would be no need to allow the last digit to fail the divisible-by-$n$ rule. So, the last digit is *probably* not $0$ (unless the rules are being intentionally tricky). Now, the $9$-digit number being divisible by $9$ implies, by a well-known rule, that the sum of the digits is divisible by $9$; since $0$ is (*probably*) one of those digits, then $9$ *cannot* be one of the other eight. (Why?) Consequently: **The number's final digit must be $9$.** (*Probably.*) Beyond that, I don't have a useful observation.

Comment: Robert's answer includes a solution with a trailing $0$, so the divisibility rule is rather unnecessarily restricted to $n=9$. Go figure. (So, the "probably"s in my above comment were warranted.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By brutish force, I find four solutions:
$$3816547209, 3816547290, 7832041659, 8016547239$$

Comment: Interestingly, you have a solution with a trailing $0$, so the divisibility rule holds for $n=10$, as well. I trust that your analysis is comprehensive, so that divisibility through $n=10$ makes the solution unique. I have to wonder why the divisibility rule only requires up to $n=9$. (I'm glad my comment to the question keeps repeating the disclaimer "probably". :)

Comment: That solution $3816547290$ is fairly "well-known".  See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandigital_number#Examples_of_base_10_pandigital_numbers).

Comment: I guess now it's even *weller*-known. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a ten digit solution, $0$ must be the tenth digit and $5$ must be the fifth.  The other evens have to go in the even places.  Each block of three digits must be divisible by $3$.  That means that either each block of three has all three digits the same $\bmod 3$ or has a $0$, a $1$, and a $2$.  The fourth and eighth place must be $2$ and $6$ (in either order) because they are preceded by an odd digit and the number to that point needs to be divisible by $4$.  The second and sixth places are then $4$ and $8$ (in either order).  This reduces the number of possibilities considerably, but there is still a bunch of trial and error.